# How to silently install exe using powershell

Tags: powershell, silent-installer, domino-designer-eclipse

I am trying to install trial version of Lotus Notes Designer using Powershell command

```
Start-Process -FilePath "EXEPath" -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "/qn"
```

But this command displays the normal installation wizard, how do I make it a silent installation?

Comment: This depends on the installer. Many (but perhaps not all) have ways to silently install, but they all differ, and sometimes some sort of unattended installation script is needed.

Answer (score 7):

Silent Install commands vary depending on the program itself and the installer they have used. Using `/qn` will work for *most* (but not all!) MSI installers, as there is a Microsoft standard that most will follow, but EXE installers can be very different as they do not have guidelines like an MSI.

Searching for the name of the program and 'silent install' will likely bring up the programs help pages or a blog which lists the commands you will need to use.

A search for "lotus notes designer silent install" brings up [this article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_8.0.1/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_USING_NOTES_SILENT_INSTALLATION_ON_WINDOWS_STEPS.html) which lists the command as:

```
setup.exe /s /v"/qn"
```

Which you would use like this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\folder\setup.exe" -Verb runAs -ArgumentList '/s','/v"/qn"'
```

Note: I can't test this as I don't use Lotus Notes, but it should work, or at least give you a good idea on what to do.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but I'm still not able to install silently using this command.

Comment: @GaurangDave Just because my answer to **this question** was not applicable to **your problem** isn't a reason for a down vote it.

Comment: For me this command worked: Start-Process -Wait -FilePath FILE_PATH -ArgumentList '/S','/v','/qn' -passthru

Answer (score 7):

Please try below command in powershell, it will install silently along with wait and ouput. Note: Your installer should be supporting /S option and didn't try with LotusNotes.

```
Start-Process .\installer.exe /S -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 Start-Process -FilePath "D:\Software\app.exe /S /NoPostReboot _?=D:\Software\app.exe" -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru $process.ExitCode
```